# CoreBluetooth - Can connectPeripheral be called multiple times

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can an application attempt to connect to multiple devices at once?

When an app calls 'connectPeripheral', it will attempt to connect for an unspecified amount of time since there is no time-out. However, if 'connectPeripheral' is called a second time, does it cancel out the previous call, or will the app attempt to make two separate connections at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my testing I've seen if you call it multiple times prior to being connected, it will take longer to actually connect (and often actually prevents a connection from occurring), but usually functions as normal after that.

However, the one massive thing I've noticed is if you try calling `connectPeripheral:` inside of the `didConnectPeripheral:` callback, you will put yourself in an infinite loop that keeps returning on `didConnectPeripheral:` over and over again.

Long story short, every single `connectPeripheral:` call should be matched with a `cancelPeripheralConnection:` (or `didDisconnectPeripheral:`) call if you don't want undefined behavior like this to happen.

Comment: When you say there will be a delay when calling `connectPeripheral` multiple times,is that when trying to call connect multiple times on the same device, or once on multiple devices? Or Both?

Comment: That's per device, but I was also testing with multiple devices and calling connectPeripheral multiple times on each

Comment: Ah, I see. I only intend to call connect once per device, so I should be good. Thanks for your response!